# php unlink problems - file exists

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having trouble with unlink in php... The files in the directory are uploaded with php form.

ls -l of /files/uploads/

```
total 6976
-rw-r--r--  1 alex  admin   689030 15 Aug 11:40 01805_goneclubbing_1680x1050.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 alex  admin   174932 15 Aug 11:52 4vvF60D.tmp.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 alex  admin  2699554 15 Aug 12:16 example.JPG
```

php script (cakePHP framework):

```
$file_path = '/files/uploads/';
    $file_name = $file['Upload']['path'];

    $classroom_id = $file['Upload']['classroom_id'];

        if (unlink($file_path . $file_name)) {

            if ($this->Upload->delete($id)) {
                $this->setFlash('File deleted');
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'classrooms', 'action' => 'view', $classroom_id));
            }

        }
```

php error:

```
Warning (2): unlink(/files/uploads/example.JPG) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory [APP/controllers/uploads_controller.php, line 55]
```

I searched on stackoverflow, tried giving 777 permissions and still not working. I can access the image through the browser at that path.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could be using CakePHP's [`File()` library](http://api.cakephp.org/class/file) (e.g. `File::delete()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On any UNIX system, `/` is your system root. So when you try to access `/files`, you try to access a folder `files` located at your system root. I think you want to access `/path_to_www/files`, so either use a variable which stores your base path or use a relative path.

On the other hand, when you try to access `/files` from your web browser, it reaches the `/` of your web directory (or an alias path). So it is totally normal that you can access your image from your browser but not from php.

Comment: Indeed. CakePHP has [constants](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1141/Core-Definition-Constants) such as `WWW_ROOT` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have an opening slash in your file path which is telling the application to look at `root`, not from your current location.  You should change your path to include a `.`,so that it is

`./files/uploads/example.JPG.`

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what the problem is - the file `$file_path . $file_name` doesn't exist. Echo it out - does it equal what you think it should?

You are referencing the storage location cannonically ('relative' to the root directory /) - did you mean to? Is there actually a directory called `/files` on your box? If there is I would be surprised...

You should make it `if (is_file($file_path . $file_name) && unlink($file_path . $file_name))` in case the file has gone missing because of an external cause to get rid of the ugly error message, and probably also do `$file_name = ltrim($file['Upload']['path'],'/');` to get rid of any stray leading slashes...

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing `getcwd()` to make sure you're in the directory you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

> ls -l of /files/uploads/

You did this with your user account/shell, didn't you?
*Maybe* the process running php "sees" the file system differently than your user account does (e.g. a chroot environment or something like that).

```
<?php
$file_path = '/files/uploads/';
$file_name = $file['Upload']['path'];
$classroom_id = $file['Upload']['classroom_id'];

// <-- debug
echo '<pre>files in ', $file_path, ":\n";
foreach( glob($file_path.'*') as $f) {
    echo "'", $f, "'\n";
}
echo "----\n</pre>\n";
// debug -->
if (unlink($file_path . $file_name)) {

    if ($this->Upload->delete($id)) {
        $this->setFlash('File deleted');
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'classrooms', 'action' => 'view', $classroom_id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup... or use CakePHP's [`Folder::read()`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/folder#method-Folderread)